# x-axis is not completely visible on highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using Angular 9. x-axis is not completely visible in my chart.
We are setting height from out side of highcharts element, tried to change height and find the issue. It didn't work.
I'm adding it's screenshot at below.
I tried several ways to fix it but i couldn't find the solution.
How can i fix the issue?

Here the project : https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-3ra6nr

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor? You can start from this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line

Comment: Thank you for response. I created project as you said. Here : stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-3ra6nr   @SebastianWędzel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the marginBottom property from the chart config fixes the issue.

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'line',
  zoomType: 'x',
  marginRight: 160,
  //marginBottom: 25,
},
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-tfxsmn

Comment: Wow , i couldn't see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GülayKülekçi you're welcome ;) please accept my answer as a solution - might be useful for other users in the future